# How to display a multi-valued parameter onto a SSRS report in a specific way, separated in ranges and/or commas

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In SSRS I need to display a multi-valued parameter onto the report in such a way that if values are chosen in sequence they appear as: 1-5, 7, 9-10, 15 and so on. And I have the following values in my drop down list of values: from '0' to '200'.

Thanks in advance for your help.

This is what I have done in SQL so far, so I am thinking to update 'String_To_Use' column so it would display: 0000-1020, 1199-1210, 1260, 1299. Then use this string to display onto the SSRS report. These are the values  chosen in SSRS from the drop down box. I don't know yet how I would pass these values to the SQL code yet. Please help with this part as well.

[This is the #tempTable1...column 'DPRTMNT' has the values chosen ...Checking_Dept has the value-2 when values in ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FepAw.png)

[This is the #tempTable2..I need to update 'String_To_Use' column so it would contain: 0000-1020, 1199-1210, 1260, 1299.  #tempTable1 can help to build the logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOn8j.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: @Jack - so if he says he has no idea where to start you'll show him the answer? Not sure how that would help getting a "more specific answer".

Comment: Join function might help.. https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s187/multivalue-report-builder.htm

Comment: There's not a built in function that would help consolidate the numbers into ranges (1,2,3,4,5 = 1-5). You would need to write a custom function that would go through the list and concatenate the pieces together in a string. It's seems like a lot of effort for little results.

Comment: Is this of any use? This example relates to ages and we'd probably need to see your data for anything more specific.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/group-expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

replace dsBranchPlant with name of your data set that your using to supply data parameter. And "All" condition is if all params are choosen instead of showing each one. Game this up as an expression and see where you stand.

```
iif(Parameters!BranchPlant.Count = CountRows("dsBranchPlant"),"ALL",Join(Parameters!BranchPlant.Label,","))
```